# Program telling me to initialize variable that does not need to be initialized when writing a simple c++ code

Tags: c++

```
double distance, point, point1, point2;
double x1,y1;
double x2, y2;

point1 = pow((y1-y1),2);
point2 = pow((x1-x2),2);

point = point1+point2;

distance = sqrt(point) ;
```

I am writing a simple c++ program to prompt the user to enter 2 coordinates and calculate the distance between them. When adding the sqrt function, I am getting that I should initialize variables x1,x2,y1,y2. I did so but I got an answer of 0 for the distance. 
What is the problem and how is resolvable?

Comment: In your code they are not initialized.

Comment: where are you taking input from user

Comment: Declaring =/= initializing

Comment: Reading the value of uninitialized variables is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You cannot predict what will happen. Your variables may all be 0 this time, but next time they may have any other value. You can't even be sure it will run at all.

Comment: no one here will teach you to code in C++, grab a tutorial for the first steps.

Comment: @Slava correct, because all I had was 0 in the output for the distance

Comment: @ArpitSolanki It is further down, the issue is not in the input

Comment: Further down? Like in after this code portion? Well of course it won't work because when you use them, they are not initialized.

Comment: C++ performs operations as soon as it reaches them. You cannot set up a formula (`pow((y1-y1),2)`) and expect `point1` to be updated as the Y values are filled in by the user. You can do exactly this in some other languages, and I wish I could remember the term for this sort of ordering because it would leave you with a keyword to research. Maybe someone else can remember it. Curse my failing, old mind.

Comment: You must always initialize ALL your variables in C/C++. Initialization (setting an initial value) is a separate step from declaration (setting aside a block of memory for use and giving it a name). It does NOT manage ANY memory allocated. It is quite likely here is leftover data in the block you are allocating. if you do not overwrite this random garbage with known values, the results are unpredictable. Also be aware that C has no garbage collection, meaning your program's memory isn't automatically freed when the variable is no longer in scope. Don't forget to destroy what you construct.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the problem and how is resolvable?
>
> It is further down, the issue is not in the input

You need to read a textbook and understand basics of the language. Statements executed from left to right, from top to bottom. So if you have user input further down you get user input **after** you used unitiliazed variables for calculation. Code that you write are not mathematical equations, but instructions to virtual C++ machine what to do in each step.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing is not the same thing as declaring.
To initialize a variable, you need to give it a value:

```
double x1 = 2.0;
double x2 = 3.7;
```

Obviously, hard-coding a value is not very useful. You should get the input from the user or some other external source.

Comment: Thanks, but in the given it is mentioned that I have to prompt the user to input values. I did further down: cout<<"Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point:"<<endl;
    cin>>x1>>y1;

    cout<<"Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point:"<<endl;
    cin>>x2>>y2;

Comment: I suggest you look at std::cin or scanf. A bit of advice though: I am seeing your question get downvoted, mainly because this stuff can be found with some simple searching online. You should probably do more research on tutorial sites and maybe even retract the question.

Answer (score 1):

This mean declaring only

```
double distance, point, point1, point2;
double x1,y1;
double x2, y2;
```

but you should:

```
double distance{ 0.0 };
double point{ 0.0 };
double point1{ 0.0 };
double point2{ 0.0 };
double x1{ 0.0 };
double y1{ 0.0 };
double x2{ 0.0 };
double y2{ 0.0 };
```

on the other hand, your equation is wrong, you have to do:

```
point1 = pow((y2 - y1), 2);    // y2 - y1 
point2 = pow((x2 - x1), 2);    // x2 - x1
```

instead of

```
point1 = pow((y1-y1),2);  // y1 - y1 is 0
point2 = pow((x1-x2),2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define local variables, they are not automatically initialized. They will haven an *indeterminate* value, and their use will lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you want your local variables to actually have a value you need to *initialize* them.

Also note that initialization does not work backwards. Without loops C++ executes the statements from top to bottom. If you initialize variables after you use them, that won't magically go back in time or otherwise redo the calculations using the uninitialized variables.

---

As for the wrong answer, that's really a separate question but it all depends on what values you initialized the variables with. And if you get the input *after* you use the variables then as stated above the calculations won't be redone.

The flow of control should be like this:

```
variable declarations and definitions (possible with initializations)

get input from user

do calculations using the input from the user
```